# How to repaint a specific area (e.g. circle) in java?

Tags: java, repaint

I am trying to make a simple game where you basically have to hit the circles to get a point. But i faced a tiny problem which i couldn't really solve on my own so here is my question how do I repaint a round surface.I used the repaint(Rectangle r) method but it doesn't workout.

```
    public void objectHit(MouseEvent e) {
    int distance = 0, deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0, RadiusSqaured = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        deltaX = e.getX() - obj[i].getPoint().x;
        deltaY = e.getY() - obj[i].getPoint().y;
        distance = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
        RadiusSqaured = obj[i].getRadius() * obj[i].getRadius();
        if (distance <= RadiusSqaured) {
            repaint(obj[i].repaintRect());
            x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50 + radius / 2, 850 - radius / 2);
            y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60 + radius / 2, 750 - radius / 2);
            repaint(obj[i].repaintRect());
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JComponent, there is a method for repainting based on a box area. Does this satisfy your requirements?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint-long-int-int-int-int-